# C language structure is not woking properly in my code

Tags: c

please take a look at the code below.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    
    struct str {
        char st[1];
        char rule[20];
    } production_rules[30];
    
    int main () {
        int n;
        printf("Enter number of productions: ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        printf("Enter the productions\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("Enter the non terminal: ");
            scanf("%s", production_rules[i].st);
            printf("Enter the RHS of the production Rule: ");
            scanf("%s", production_rules[i].rule);
        }
        printf("the production rules are \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("%s -> %s\n", production_rules[i].st, production_rules[i].rule);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

I am getting the following output

```
Enter number of productions: 1
Enter the productions
Enter the non terminal: A
Enter the RHS of the production Rule: abc
the production rules are
Aabc -> abc
```

Expected Output:

```
Enter number of productions: 1
Enter the productions
Enter the non terminal: A
Enter the RHS of the production Rule: abc
the production rules are
A -> abc
```

The problem is in the last line of the output. I don't understand why the char array is being concatenated. Can some one help me with this problem

Comment: `char st[1];` isn't large enough to hold a zero terminated string. You need at least 2 characters.

Comment: What happens if you output the return values (which you currently ignore) of all of your uses of scan()?

Comment: please change  `char st[1];`  to `char st[2];` (or if you expect the string to be longer, change to a bigger value for the array length)

Comment: Tip: A length 1 array is almost always *completely useless*. Either that's just a single value, as in a normal variable, or a mistake.

Comment: `%s` means the argument must be pointer to null-terminated string, anything else is undefined behaviour

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue in your struct, but just the way you use printf, as you put %s to print the element "st", whilst you should use "%c" instead.

In fact, "st" is just a char[1], not a proper string, so it doesn't contain the string termination character '\0'.
As your struct is stored in memory as a buffer of consecutive char, the "%s" makes the "printf" stop when the termination string character is found, so at the end of the element "rule", and that's reason of your output.
So, just replace %s with %c when printf of st and it will work. Your code should appear like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%c -> %s\n", production_rules[i].st, production_rules[i].rule);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem was: not having a sufficient number of rooms in that character array. It is because the null-terminator character is always put at the end of the string, so it requires extra space.

In the current situation, your requirement is only a single character. So, you can change it into a `char` in the struct definition:

```
struct str {
    char st;
    char rule[20];
} production_rules[30];
```

And use it this way:

```
scanf(" %c", &production_rules[i].st);
```

Notice that an extra whitespace character is given here because it is necessary. Otherwise, it would simply ignore the input from being given.

---

Another method to solve this issue is to increase the length of the array by one. Suppose, you need 3 numbers as `char[]` then you need a length of 4 (extra one).